# How to activate refactorings?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-xe7, delphi-ide

The Refactorings menu in my C++/Delphi always shows "No refactorings available". How do I activate it? It seems promising. I would like to use it one day.

There is a very old thread here saying that this is caused by some disabled packages. But I have ALL packages (except two MS Office packages) enabled.

Comment: Once you activate it be prepared for it not to perform well

Comment: Which edition are you using? Starter, Professional, Enterprise or Architect?

Comment: Delphi XE7 Pro and C++ Builder Tokyo Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a project open for the "Refactor" menu to be active.

Then it depends on if you are in design view or code view what items are active.

Comment: @Rigel *of course I have a menu loaded*, **menu**? I said **project**, which I assume you meant to write. Do you speak about the main menu *Refactor* menu or the popup menu *Refactor* menu or both? I don't recall having to do anything special during installation to get it working. If there was an installation option ticked and you unticked it, you will need to run the installer again.

Comment: Hi. Yes, of course I have a Project loaded. And the menu is still "empty" no matter if I am in Code or Form design view. –

Comment: sorry. I meant "project". sorry.